# Flutter tflite MoveNet model java.lang.RuntimeException: doInBackground()

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was trying to implement MoveNet tflite pose estimation model on Flutter via https://pub.dev/packages/tflite package. MoveNet lightning model accepts 192x192 image size and uses float32 tensor of shape. I loaded the lightning model and camera streaming like this :

```
class _AppCameraState extends State<AppCamera> {
  late CameraController controller;
  bool isDetecting = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.cameras!.length < 1) {
      print('No camera is found');
    } else {
      controller = new CameraController(
        widget.cameras![0],
        ResolutionPreset.high,
      );
      controller.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});

        detectPose();
      });
    }
  }

  detectPose() {
    controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
      if (!isDetecting) {
        isDetecting = true;

        Tflite.runModelOnBinary(binary: imageToByteListFloat32(convertCameraImage(img)!, 192, 127.5, 127.5)).then((recognition) {
          widget.setRecognitions!(recognition, 192, 192);
          isDetecting = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Helper functions :

```
Uint8List imageToByteListFloat32(imgLib.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) {
    var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (imgLib.getRed(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (imgLib.getGreen(pixel) - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (imgLib.getBlue(pixel) - mean) / std;
      }
    }
    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }


imageLib.Image? convertCameraImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  if (cameraImage.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) {
    return _convertYUV420ToImage(cameraImage);
  } else if (cameraImage.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888) {
    return _convertBGRA8888ToImage(cameraImage);
  }
}

imageLib.Image _convertBGRA8888ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  imageLib.Image img = imageLib.Image.fromBytes(cameraImage.planes[0].width!, cameraImage.planes[0].height!, cameraImage.planes[0].bytes,
      format: imageLib.Format.bgra);
  return img;
}

imageLib.Image _convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final int width = cameraImage.width;
  final int height = cameraImage.height;

  final int uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final int uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

  final image = imageLib.Image(width, height);

  for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
      final int uvIndex = uvPixelStride * (w / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (h / 2).floor();
      final int index = h * width + w;

      final y = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[index];
      final u = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
      final v = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

      image.data[index] = _yuv2rgb(y, u, v);
    }
  }
  return image;
}

int _yuv2rgb(int y, int u, int v) {
  // Convert yuv pixel to rgb
  int r = (y + v * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round();
  int g = (y - u * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - v * 93604 / 131072 + 91).round();
  int b = (y + u * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round();

  // Clipping RGB values to be inside boundaries [ 0 , 255 ]
  r = r.clamp(0, 255);
  g = g.clamp(0, 255);
  b = b.clamp(0, 255);

  return 0xff000000 | ((b << 16) & 0xff0000) | ((g << 8) & 0xff00) | (r & 0xff);
}
```

And output like this below :

[image]

Which part should be edit? , thank you.

Comment: Are you performing any task Update task while executing library method.

Comment: No , I did not change any code on plugin. I'm not sure which part to edit because this plugin async task code different from official tensorflow android example :/ , example here https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/pose_estimation/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/poseestimation